# How to create a circular calculator button in Swift 5.1?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

hope you are all doing well.

I am learning iOS development as we speak. The first app I am trying to build is a calculator app. I have started building the UI and created the buttons. See code and screenshot of the app running below.

```
    private func setupNumPad(){
    let buttonSize: CGFloat = view.frame.size.width/4
    
    let zeroButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: holder.frame.size.height-buttonSize, width: buttonSize*3, height: buttonSize))
    zeroButton.setTitle("0", for: .normal)
    holder.addSubview(zeroButton)
    
    for x in 0..<3{
        let buttonOnetoThree = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: buttonSize * CGFloat(x), y: holder.frame.size.height-(buttonSize*2), width: buttonSize, height: buttonSize))
        buttonOnetoThree.setTitle("\(x+1)", for: .normal)
        holder.addSubview(buttonOnetoThree)
    }
    
    for x in 0..<3{
        let buttonFourtoSix = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: buttonSize * CGFloat(x), y: holder.frame.size.height-(buttonSize*3), width: buttonSize, height: buttonSize))
        buttonFourtoSix.setTitle("\(x+4)", for: .normal)
        holder.addSubview(buttonFourtoSix)
    }
    
    for x in 0..<3{
        let buttonSeventoNine = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: buttonSize * CGFloat(x), y: holder.frame.size.height-(buttonSize*4), width: buttonSize, height: buttonSize))
        buttonSeventoNine.setTitle("\(x+7)", for: .normal)
        holder.addSubview(buttonSeventoNine)
    }
```

[Click Here to View Image of Code Running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAfMH.png)

However, I would love it if some can explain or show me to create a circle button. Lets, say the background of the circle button I want is to be white. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

** I am not using SwiftUI **

Comment: Hint: `UIButton`.layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for x in 0..<3{
        let buttonOnetoThree = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: buttonSize * CGFloat(x), y: holder.frame.size.height-(buttonSize*2), width: buttonSize, height: buttonSize))
        // make circle button
        buttonOnetoThree.layer.cornerRadius = buttonSize/2
        buttonOnetoThree.backgroundColor = .white
        buttonOnetoThree.setTitle("\(x+1)", for: .normal)
        holder.addSubview(buttonOnetoThree)
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community. In order to create a circular button you will have to change the `layer.corderRadius` property of your buttons (Tip- The same goes for any `UIView`). To make it a perfect circle, you will have to set the `cornerRadius` to half (0.5) the value you have set for the width or height. Taking one of your `for-loop` as an example, you will have to make the following changes,

```
for x in 0..<3{
        let buttonOnetoThree = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: buttonSize * CGFloat(x), y: holder.frame.size.height-(buttonSize*2), width: buttonSize, height: buttonSize))
        buttonOnetoThree.setTitle("\(x+1)", for: .normal)
        // SETTING THE CORNER RADIUS TO MAKE A CIRCULAR BUTTON -----------------
        buttonOnetoThree.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * buttonSize // Setting corner radius to half of buttonSize
        buttonOnetoThree.clipsToBounds = true // This value makes sure that the view (Button) is within the frame defined
        holder.addSubview(buttonOnetoThree)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, your comment helped my case. I am running into a new problem where the buttons are now touching each other. I want to make the buttons a bit smaller and add spacing between them. Looking at my code, is this the best way to make a calculator?